# In LibGDX, how to stop music after Android app resumes?

Tags: android, kotlin, libgdx

I'm developing a simple game in Kotlin using LibGDX that plays music in the background. On Android, when the user is playing the game and presses the HOME button, then resumes the game once more, my pause screen appears - and the music resumes. What I want is for the music to always be off whenever my pause screen is being displayed.

When I start up a new game, whenever I press my in-game "pause" button, the music stops as intended - then starts again once I click my in-game "resume" button. That's working just fine. It's only when pressing the HOME button that I have issues.

I found this JavaDoc comment in the LibGDX doc:
https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/audio/Music.html

> Music instances are automatically paused and resumed when an Application is paused or resumed. See ApplicationListener.

That is not the behaviour I want but I can't figure out how to stop it. I've tried to stop the music when the app resumes but none of that seems to have any effect - the music always plays.

I'm using an Assets class, following the recommendations here:
[libgdx: best way to load all assets in the game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33651323/libgdx-best-way-to-load-all-assets-in-the-game/33653328)

Here's my Assets class:

```
class Assets {
    . . .
    private val manager = AssetManager()

    lateinit var backgroundMusic: Music
    . . .

    fun load() {
        manager.load(BACKGROUND_MUSIC_FILENAME, Music::class.java)
    }

    fun finishLoading() {
        // Wait for all loading to finish
        manager.finishLoading()
        . . .
        backgroundMusic = manager.get(BACKGROUND_MUSIC_FILENAME)
    }

    fun startBackgroundMusic() {
        if (Preferences.musicEnabled) {
            backgroundMusic.isLooping = true
            backgroundMusic.volume = 1f
            backgroundMusic.play()
        }
    }

    fun stopBackgroundMusic() {
        backgroundMusic.stop()
    }
. . .
}
```

My main entry point looks like this:

```
class GameEntrypoint : Game(), ScreenSwitcher {

    private val assets = Assets()

    override fun create() {
        // Start loading assets
        assets.load()

        // Wait until all assets have loaded
        assets.finishLoading()
        . . .
        mainMenuScreen = MainMenuScreen(assets, this, this.penguinGame)
        setScreen(mainMenuScreen)
    }
```

Here's my `GameScreen` where I switch to the `PauseScreen` when the app is paused:

```
class GameScreen(private val assets: Assets, private val screenSwitcher: ScreenSwitcher,  . . .) : Screen,
    InputProcessor {

    init {
        . . .
        val btnPause = ImageButton(TextureRegionDrawable(assets.imagesTextureAtlas.findRegion(Assets.BUTTON_PAUSE_REGION)))
        Gui.addClickListener(btnPause) {
            // Pause button clicked - pause the game then show pause screen
            pauseTheGame()
        }
        . . .
    }

    private fun pauseTheGame() {
        assets.stopBackgroundMusic()
        penguinGame.pauseGame()
        screenSwitcher.setScreen(pauseScreen)
    }
    . . .
}
```

I've tried calling `assets.stopBackgroundMusic()` in these places:

- In `resume()` of `GameEntrypoint`
- In `resume()` of `PauseScreen`
- In `show()` of `PauseScreen`
- Whenever the game is paused from `GameScreen`

I'm out of ideas. Any help or ideas greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe call `stopTheMusic()` at the beginning of `render()` of the PauseScreen. Seems like the auto-resume behavior of music should be configurable. You might want to open an issue.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Wow - stopping the music in the `render()` method of `PauseScreen` did the trick! I't's pretty dirty, calling it in every loop iteration, and I'd be very interested to know why it's happening at all. Interestingly, `backgroundMusic.isPlaying` returns `false` in every loop iteration, even though the music stops ok. Weird.
And yes, I will open an issue on this, good idea. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a couple of ways to resolve this issue.

It's caused by the following code in `com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication`:

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume () {
    . . .
        this.isWaitingForAudio = true;
        if (this.wasFocusChanged == 1 || this.wasFocusChanged == -1) {
            this.audio.resume(); // <--- here !!
            this.isWaitingForAudio = false;
        }
        super.onResume();
    }
```

As you can see, the audio is *always* resumed. Why? I dunno.

So to solve it, you can do one of the following:

1. Add the following code to `AndroidLauncher`:

```
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        // Work-around to prevent LibGDX from *always* restarting background music after resume
        this.audio.pause()
    }
```

This will turn the music off, straight after it's turned on again inside `super.resume()`.

2. Add the following code to the end of the `create` function in your class that extends `Game`:

```
    override fun create() {
        . . .
        // Don't play any music from when the app was last resumed
        assets.stopBackgroundMusic()
    }
```

I'd still like to know why LibGDX behaves this way.